# Google sheet script auto add new rows with copied formulas

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to create function which adds rows with copied formulas from above rows. After the script is launched it should result in accurate number (set 5 i this code) of blank rows at the end of the sheet.

The code I managed to create counts what number of rows should be added but adds only one row with copied formulas at the end.

Please help me edit this code to multiple the result of the function by "rowstoadd" parameter.

[Sheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch2qU.jpg)

```js
function autoaddRows() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Harmonogram');
  var range = sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
  var lastRowB = range.filter(String).length + 2;
  var lastRowA = sheet.getLastRow();
  var blanknrows = sheet.getLastRow() - lastRowB;
  if (blanknrows < 5) {
    let rowstoadd = 5 - blanknrows;
    Browser.msgBox(rowstoadd);
    let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let lastRowIndex = sheet.getLastRow();
    let existingRange = getRowRange(sheet, lastRowIndex);

    sheet.insertRowAfter(lastRowIndex);
    let newRange = getRowRange(sheet, ++lastRowIndex);

    existingRange.copyTo(newRange);
    newRange.setFormulas(newRange.getFormulas());
    newRange.clearNote();
  }
  
  function getRowRange(sheet, rowIndex) {
    return sheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Please help me edit this code to multiple the result of the function by "rowstoadd" parameter.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Now this code adds 1 row. I need to edit it to add number of rows which is calculated by "rowstoadd" parameter. If you look at picture attached on the left there is one blank row at the end. "Blankrow" parameter is set on 5 so I want the script to add 4 rows (which is calculated by "rowstoadd" parameter).

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your script, I cannot understand `"Blankrow" parameter is set on 5`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: "blanknrows < 5" - No matter if in sheet is 2,3 or 4 blank rows at the bottom after running script i should be always 5 blank rows. So depanding on situation script should add 3,2 or 1 row to be total 5 at the bottom as in this case 5 is blankrows parameter.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to keep 5 new empty rows.
- For example, when the last row of column "A" is 10 and the last row of column "B" is 9, you want to add 4 new rows.
- Also, you want to put the formula to the column "B" of the inserted rows.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function autoaddRows() {
  var addRows = 5;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Harmonogram');
  var range = sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
  var lastRowB = range.filter(String).length + 1;
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var blanknrows = lastRow - lastRowB;
  var diff = addRows - blanknrows;
  if (diff > 0) {
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(lastRow, diff);
    // var range = sheet.getRange("B" + lastRowB);
    // range.copyTo(range.offset(1, 0, diff + 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
    var numberOfCol = sheet.getLastColumn() - 1;
    var range = sheet.getRange(lastRowB, 2, 1, numberOfCol);
    range.copyTo(range.offset(1, 0, diff + 1, numberOfCol), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
    range.clearNote();
  }
}
```

- In this modification, the difference between the last rows between column "A" and column "B" is retrieved. And the empty rows are inserted using the difference.
- In your script, `newRange.clearNote();` is used. So, I also add `range.clearNote();`. If you want to remove it, please remove it.

#### References:

- [insertRowsAfter(afterPosition, howMany)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsafterafterposition,-howmany)
- [copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed)

Comment: It's almost perfect :) But look at picture attached (on the left --> Before) and imagine that B5 has formula which is results in blank cell. Now the script copies only the last value from column B. (addrows=5 it displays 5 rows with "3M 22 02 2022") It should copy the the whole first blank row with formulas in cells - not only column B.

Comment: @Michał Kostrzewa Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From `It should copy the the whole first blank row with formulas in cells - not only column B.`, I updated my proposed script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your actual goal in your replying, I apologize again. At that time, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: With my small change it works just I wanted. Thanks a million! (var range = sheet.getRange(lastRowB+1, 2, 1, numberOfCol);)

Comment: @Michał Kostrzewa Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `One more thing. How it should be modified to copy row with formating (specially with coloured borders in cells)?`, how about putting `range.copyTo(range.offset(1, 0, diff + 1, numberOfCol), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);` before the line of `range.clearNote();`? If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.

Comment: It works for the first time, but for the second it doesn't. Look at the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PEudZEXyc49qOtwpeZ2u1YoG_z-YpcV8JaDU_YaN2TM/edit#gid=1363132284   First run the script with the button, it will add rows, then add some records in column B and C and run it again. You will see that it creates rows but does not copy formatting anymore.

Comment: @Michał Kostrzewa Thank you for replying. I apologize that your new question is still not resolved. In that case, can you post it as new question by including more information? Because I think that your new question is different from your initial question, and furthermore, I think that your new question will be also useful for other users. By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: I made a new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70811101/copying-the-row-with-formatting-multiple-times-using-auto-adding-rows-script-in     I am an amateur trying to improve my work through google sheets. I have no developer knowledge. It's all based on reading this forum and trying different solutions. In this case, I can't understand why the script works the first time and not the second time. I tried changing the numerical parameters but so far I have not found a solution. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Michał Kostrzewa Thank you for your response. I checked it and proposed a modification point.